# Как наладить взаимодействие между контекстами приложений в java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, столкнулась с такой задачей: есть несколько приложений написанных на Java,расположенных на разных адресах. Необходимо наладить взаимодействие между ними(обмен сообщениями) . По средством использования каких  технологий это возможно?

Comment: можно письма слать друг другу =)

Comment: Посмотрите на сокеты.

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный способ взаимодействия двух приложений находящихся в разных JVM это [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation), в качестве извращения и гимнастики для ума можно применить [Corba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture)

Если речь идет о взаимодействии двух серверных приложений (servlet/JSP) находящихся в разных серверах, то можно проще обойтись обработкой `doGet()/doPost()`

**Update**

Если речь идет о двух разных серверных приложениях, но в пределах 1-го сервера, то есть способ достучаться до другого контекста средствами `ServletContext.getContext(String uriPath)`, правда при этом в `server.xml` должно быть явно прописано разрешение на доступ к контексту из другого контекста. В частности в Tomcat атрибут `crossContext` элемента `Context` должен быть выставлен в `true`. См. [например здесь](http://www.akadia.com/download/soug/tomcat/html/tomcat_server_xml.html)

Comment: приложения серверные, есть подсистема безопасности доступ к объектам осуществляется после авторизации. обработкой doGet()/doPost() смогу ли я обойти безопасность?

Comment: Если система безопасности нормальная, то `doGet()/doPost()` не обойдут ее. Если есть основной сервлет контроллер (согласно MVC), то запросы все равно пойдут через контроллер, который и выведет на авторизацию.

Comment: @Ольга см. апдейт

Comment: А что на счет JMS ?